# JScrollPane with rulers didn't work

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I've tried to run the example found in Java Swing 2nd Edition 7.1.3 ScrollPaneLayout. The image and the scroll have worked just fine, but the ruler hasn't. Here's my code:

```
public class ScrollPaneLayoutDemo extends JFrame{
    JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("img.jpg"));

    public ScrollPaneLayoutDemo() {
        super("ScrollPaneLayout Demo");

        JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(label);

        JLabel[] corners = new JLabel[4];

        for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
        {
            corners[i] = new JLabel();
            corners[i].setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
            corners[i].setOpaque(true);
            corners[i].setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2, 2, 2, 2), BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED, 1)));
        }

        JLabel rowheader = new JLabel() {
            Font f = new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC | Font.BOLD, 10);

            public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
            {
                super.paintComponent(g);

                Rectangle r = g.getClipBounds();
                g.setFont(f);
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                for (int i = 50 - (r.y % 50); i < r.height; i += 50) {
                      g.drawLine(0, r.y + i, 3, r.y + i);
                      g.drawString("" + (r.y + i), 6, r.y + i + 3);
                }
            }

            public Dimension getPreferredSize() 
            {
                return new Dimension(25, (int) label.getPreferredSize().getHeight());
            }
        };
        rowheader.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        rowheader.setOpaque(true);

        JLabel columnheader = new JLabel() {
            Font f = new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC | Font.BOLD, 10);

            public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
            {
                super.paintComponent(g);

                Rectangle r = g.getClipBounds();
                g.setFont(f);
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                for (int i = 50 - (r.x % 50); i < r.width; i += 50) 
                {
                      g.drawLine(r.x + i, 0, r.x + i, 3);
                      g.drawString("" + (r.x + i), r.x + i - 10, 16);
                }
            }

            public Dimension getPreferredSize()
            {
                return new Dimension((int) label.getPreferredSize().getWidth(),25);
            }
        };
        columnheader.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        columnheader.setOpaque(true);

        jsp.setRowHeaderView(rowheader);
        jsp.setColumnHeaderView(columnheader);
        jsp.setCorner(JScrollPane.LOWER_LEFT_CORNER, corners[0]);
        jsp.setCorner(JScrollPane.LOWER_RIGHT_CORNER, corners[1]);
        jsp.setCorner(JScrollPane.UPPER_LEFT_CORNER, corners[2]);
        jsp.setCorner(JScrollPane.UPPER_RIGHT_CORNER, corners[3]);

        getContentPane().add(jsp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(400, 300);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JScrollPaneDemo();
    }
}
```

If anyone could help me with this issue I appreciate.

Comment: `public class ScrollPaneLayoutDemo extends JFrame{` <> / != `new JScrollPaneDemo();`

Answer (score 3):

- Dimension from child must be greater than JViewports Dimension (visible rectangle from JScrollPane), then JScrollBars or custom decorations can be visible, more in Oracle tutorial How to use ScrollPanes
- search for @Annotations

e.g.

no idea why but I can't add image here :-)

from

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ScrollPaneLayoutDemo extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("img.jpg")) {
        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(new Dimension(800, 600));/*icon.getIconWidth(), icon.getIconHeight()*/
        }
    };

    public ScrollPaneLayoutDemo() {
        super("ScrollPaneLayout Demo");
        label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(label);
        JLabel[] corners = new JLabel[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            corners[i] = new JLabel();
            corners[i].setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
            corners[i].setOpaque(true);
            corners[i].setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2, 2, 2, 2), BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED, 1)));
        }
        JLabel rowheader = new JLabel() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            Font f = new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC | Font.BOLD, 10);

            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                Rectangle r = g.getClipBounds();
                g.setFont(f);
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                for (int i = 50 - (r.y % 50); i < r.height; i += 50) {
                    g.drawLine(0, r.y + i, 3, r.y + i);
                    g.drawString("" + (r.y + i), 6, r.y + i + 3);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(25, (int) label.getPreferredSize().getHeight());
            }
        };
        rowheader.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        rowheader.setOpaque(true);
        JLabel columnheader = new JLabel() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            Font f = new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC | Font.BOLD, 10);

            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                Rectangle r = g.getClipBounds();
                g.setFont(f);
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                for (int i = 50 - (r.x % 50); i < r.width; i += 50) {
                    g.drawLine(r.x + i, 0, r.x + i, 3);
                    g.drawString("" + (r.x + i), r.x + i - 10, 16);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension((int) label.getPreferredSize().getWidth(), 25);
            }
        };
        columnheader.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        columnheader.setOpaque(true);
        jsp.setRowHeaderView(rowheader);
        jsp.setColumnHeaderView(columnheader);
        jsp.setCorner(JScrollPane.LOWER_LEFT_CORNER, corners[0]);
        jsp.setCorner(JScrollPane.LOWER_RIGHT_CORNER, corners[1]);
        jsp.setCorner(JScrollPane.UPPER_LEFT_CORNER, corners[2]);
        jsp.setCorner(JScrollPane.UPPER_RIGHT_CORNER, corners[3]);
        getContentPane().add(jsp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(400, 300);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ScrollPaneLayoutDemo();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Plus one. *"no idea why but I can't add image here"* and *"plus isn't accesible in commments, not allowed here"* sounds like you are having a great user experience in SO today.